# Implementation of Hilbert Spectrum in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, hilbert-transform

I am trying to implement this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPyeU.png)  on Matlab,  where i have wj values in the form of an array, *cumtrapz* command of MATLAB implements this, but its confusing which way is exact. such as *cumtrapz(t,wj)* or simply *cumtrapz(wj)* or manually doing it? Because results of all these though related, are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\omega$ is a vector with all the discrete elements $\omega_{j}$ over the descrete time steps $dt$ the correct formula would be `dt*cumtrapz(omega);` which is the same as `cumtrapz(dt,omega)` or alternatively if $dt$ isn't constant but $t$ is a vector with evaluation positions `Omega=cumtrapz(t,omega,2)`. The "2" is needed to indicate that the 2nd vector should be integrated.
[image: Function omega and its integration using cumtrapz]

Comment: I have 't' values in a 1d array, and omega values at each time point 't' in another.

Comment: Then cumtrapz(t,omega,2) is the way to go